# I need user's email address after successful facebook login in android using SDK 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk, facebook-login

I have integrated latest Facebook android sdk 4.0. In SDK 3.0+ user's email address is retreived using user.getProperty("email") after successful login. I am looking for corresponding command in Facebook Android sdk 4.0
Reference Links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#overview
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "user_likes", "user_friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    setFacebookLoginText(loginButton);
    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                  //Need User email address after login success.

                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook_login, container, false);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah, it worked. The only thing required was to change `GraphRequest` to `GraphRequestAsyncTask` in `onSuccess` method of `FacebookCallBack`, and then user details could easily be fetched from the `JSONObject`.

```
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            final FBUser fbUser = new FBUser();
            GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    fbUser.setEmail(user.optString("email"));
                    fbUser.setName(user.optString("name"));
                    fbUser.setId(user.optString("id"));
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
```

FBUser Model Class

```
public class FBUser {
private String displayName;
private String email;

public FBUser(String displayName, String email) {
    this.displayName= displayName;
    this.email = email;
}

public FBUser() {

}

public String getName() {
    return displayName;
}

public void setName(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

Comment: how you can store the GraphRequest type object to a GraphRequestAsyncTask  type reference, it's not working

Comment: i am using custom button on click and FacebookManager .. after successful login .. i am not getting ca;; to this onSuccess(). can please tell me proper way to get this info.

Comment: yup, its working, but I am only getting username and id, not getting email and profile photo from it

Comment: You need permission for getting email of user.

LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");

And for getting profile photo of user, You need to make another API call to Facebook with id of user.

"http:// graph.facebook.com/v2.3/"+ <user-id>+"/picture?redirect=false&type=large";

This will return you the url of user profile picture.

Answer (score 5):

In the new facebook graph you need to ask permissions for access that information. for example on the activity you have put the LoginButton you add this line in the OnCreate method

```
loginButtonFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"));
```

Then you get that information

```
loginButtonFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {
                if (response.getError() != null) {
                    // handle error
                } else {
                    String email = me.optString("email");
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the information from facebook sdk 4.0.0

fbloginButton.setReadPermissions("email");

```
    fbloginButton.registerCallback(callbackmanager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
           GraphRequest graphRequest=GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
               @Override
               public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                   if (response.getError()!=null)
                   {
                       Log.e(TAG,"Error in Response "+ response);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       email=object.optString("email");
                       Log.e(TAG,"Json Object Data "+object+" Email id "+ email);
                   }


               }
           });

            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("fields","id,email,name");
            graphRequest.setParameters(bundle);
            graphRequest.executeAsync();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that, test if you have permission, otherwise ask to your users again:

```
AccessToken accessToken=AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
if (accessToken.getPermissions().contains("email")) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: BTW I think there is a bug regarding this: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/issues/51